# How to set OnTap/ Touch listener to googleMap Marker when using compass, the map rotate auto

Tags: android, google-maps

1. i build navigate application using google map, the map is rotate automaticly by the compass.

the problem is when i set markers.

i am using OnTap(int) in my extended ItemizedOverlay, for popup Toast msg when i click on marker, it works fine on standard use of google map.
But, because i use map that rotate by the compass the touch listener dont rotate with the map.
only the markers are rotate ok with the map but the touch listeners stays in other place on scereen.

SomeOne know how to referesh markers louch location or how to fix it?

thank You!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use mapView.postInvalidate() to refresh the markers whenever your map is rotated by the compass. I'm not entirely sure if this will work because I've never faced this sort of a situation. Do let me know what happens.